# Use Pear Mail on MAMP

Tags: php, pear, mamp

I use MAMP 2.1.1 (not MAMP Pro) on my Mac OS X. I want to write some php code to send out html emails.

I've installed mail, mail_mime, and net_smtp. When I tried the example found on http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php, I always get "500 Internal Server Error". I checked php_error.log, it says "PHP Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found". And I tried

```
<?php
require_once('Mail.php');
var_dump(class_exists('Mail', false));
?>
```

it returns bool(false) bool(false)

I checked all files and paths, everything seems fine. And I tried the same codes on a ubuntu server, everything is fine.

Could anyone tell me how can I fix this problem?

Comment: is the pear php dir in your incude path? Try get_include_path() to see your current path

Comment: Thanks for your reply, WayneC! The output is ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php" and I checked all extension files (including Mail.php, Pear.php, etc) are under this path. The email still cannot be sent out.

Answer (score 0):

I clean installed Mountain Lion this year, and I am using built-in apache, php and mysql instead of MAMP right now. However I found this problem still exists in my current environment.

But I have an imperfect solution can make the code work. I put this line before calling require/require_once:

`ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ':/usr/lib/php/pear');`

then the mail function can work.

Without this line, the include path on my machine is `.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php`. You can see that the problem is caused by the incorrect path. Due to some reason, PEAR was installed in a different path and the php.ini is not set correctly.

You can try this solution on your machine. First find out your pear installing path, then change that line accordingly and put it in your code.

Hope this solution can give you a little hint. And if you can share a better solution, I would appreciate it!